# how to use bind a 1D array to a texture object

Tags: cuda

I want to use texture memory of GPU for a 1D array and use it in a kernal.
I create a texture object and and assigned `resDesc.res.linear.devPtr` to a device array to bind my desired array to texture object. The problem is that when I fetch the data, it is different from the data I bounded to the texture memory. The output of this code should be 1, 4, 9, ... while it is 0,0,0,....

```
#include<cuda.h>
#include<cuda_runtime.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;
// Simple transformation kernel
__global__ void squareKernel(float* output,float *dh, int size,  cudaTextureObject_t texObj) {
    unsigned int x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if(x>size)return;
    float y=tex1D<float>(texObj, x);
    printf("%d, %f, %f\n", x, y, dh[x]);
    output[x]=y*y;
}
#define width 10
int main() {
    cudaChannelFormatDesc channelDesc = cudaCreateChannelDesc(width, 0, 0, 0,
            cudaChannelFormatKindFloat);
    float *hA=(float *)malloc(width*sizeof(float));
    for(int i=0;i<width;i++){
        hA[i]=i;
    }
    float *dA;
    cudaMalloc((void **)&dA, width*sizeof(float));
    cudaMemcpy(dA, hA, width*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    
    cudaResourceDesc resDesc;
    memset(&resDesc, 0, sizeof(resDesc));

    resDesc.resType = cudaResourceTypeLinear;
    resDesc.res.linear.devPtr=dA;
    resDesc.res.linear.sizeInBytes=width*sizeof(float);
    
    // Specify texture object parameters
    cudaTextureDesc texDesc;
    memset(&texDesc, 0, sizeof(texDesc));

    texDesc.filterMode = cudaFilterModeLinear;
    texDesc.readMode = cudaReadModeElementType;
    texDesc.normalizedCoords = 0;
    // Create texture object
    cudaTextureObject_t texObj = 0;
    cudaCreateTextureObject(&texObj, &resDesc, &texDesc, NULL);



    float* output;
    cudaMalloc(&output, width * sizeof(float));
    squareKernel<<<1, width>>>(output, dA, width,texObj);
    cudaMemcpy(hA, output, width*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    for(int i=0; i<width;i++){
        cout<<i<<","<<hA[i]<<endl;
    }
    
    // Destroy texture object
    cudaDestroyTextureObject(texObj);
    // Free device memory

    cudaFree(dA);
    free(hA);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "The problem is that when I fetch the data" -- what problem would that be? Could you explain in a bit more detail about what isn't working?

Comment: @talonmies, I already edited the question.

Comment: OK. So it doesn't seem you have defined a channel description anywhere in your code. I would guess that cudaCreateTextureObject is failing with an error, but you don't check for runtime errors, so no-one could say for sure

Comment: # compute-sanitizer ./t47
========= COMPUTE-SANITIZER
========= Program hit cudaErrorInvalidChannelDescriptor (error 20) due to "invalid channel descriptor" on CUDA API call to cudaCreateTextureObject.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can simply replace the `tex1D<float>(texObj, x);` by  `tex1Dfetch<float>(texObj, x);`

One use `tex1D` when the resource data is stored in a `cuArray`.

Comment: How will that fix a texture definition without a  valid channel description?

Comment: @talonmies Sorry, I did not see the details about the channel description in this code, but I think the cause of the zero output is the usage of `tex1D`, and I found a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37080835/how-to-bind-a-float-array-to-a-1d-texture-in-cuda?rq=1).

Comment: The texture isn’t even created. Did you try running your answer? I guess not..